# OOP pattern for indicators (variables, parameters) and its values

Tags: java, oop

What is the best way from the OOP point of view to implement immutable classes for some indicators(parameters, variables) and their values.

Below there is pseudocode for the approach I am currently using

```
class Indicator
{
    private String key;   // Key
    private String desc;  // Description

    public Indicator(String _key, String _desc)
    {
        key = _key;
        desc = _desc;
    }

    public String getKey()  { return key; }
    public String getDesc() { return desc; }
}

class IndicatorValue extends Indicator
{
    private int val;

    public IndicatorValue(String _key, String  _desc, int _val)
    {
        super(_key, _desc);
        val = _val;        
    }

    public int getVal()  { return val; }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be pseudo-code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes)

Comment: It's almost fine, I would also declare the fields as `final` so their value cannot be modified inside the class either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a pure data object, you don't really need encapsulation, which in Java requires quite a lot of boilerplate code. You can also have simple `public final` fields:

```
public class Indicator {
    public final String key, desc;

    public Indicator(String key, String desc) { 
        this.key = key; this.desc = desc; 
    }
}
```

In some specific situations the getters become necessary, but I wouldn't recommend starting your design with them. They should prove to be worth their weight.

Comment: there is a point from `getters`, when a i need to make the `properties` states immutable, in getters i return `copies` properties, but , i guess, OP doesn't need this..

Comment: @EugenHalca That's one of the points, yes. Other common cases are where you use a framework which insists on getters.